# Is there a way to delay mouseleave in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code that changes the background with mouseover and goes back to the initial background jpg on mouseleave. I've put transitions between photos which work fine but when I unhover the mouse before the transition is finished it just cuts away with no transition at all.
I want to make it so my code will delay mouseleave for 700 ms until transition from mouseover is finished.

HTML

```
    <div class=box>
        <div id='pic'></div>
        <ul id=ul>
            <li rel='zero' class="active"><a href="#" data-text="zero"></a></li>
            <li rel="one"><a href="#" onclick='sizeup()' data-text='Model'>Model</a></li> 
            <li rel="two"><a href="#" onclick='sizeup()' data-text='Actor'>Actor</a></li> 
            <li rel="three"><a href="#" onclick='sizeup()' data-text='Gamer'>Gamer</a></li>

        </ul>
```

JS

```
        var s = $('ul li').on("mouseover",function(){
            $('#pic').removeClass().addClass(
                $(this).attr('rel'));
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            });
        $("ul li").on("mouseleave",function(){
            $('#pic').removeClass().addClass('zero');
            $(this).removeClass('active')});
```

Comment: Showing your css would be helpful

Comment: you can use `setTimeout` in the event callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a timeout, make sure to cancel the timeout if the user goes back into the element

```js
$("ul li")
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    if (this.timer) window.clearTimeout(this.timer);
    $(this).addClass("active");
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    this.timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      elem.removeClass("active");
    }, 200);
  });
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Foo 1</li>
  <li>Foo 2</li>
  <li>Foo 3</li>
  <li>Foo 4</li>
  <li>Foo 5</li>
</ul>
```

Or the issue might just be your CSS not having the right transition code on both directions.

```js
$("li[data-img]").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function (evt) {
  $(".out").toggleClass(this.dataset.img, evt.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

```css
.out {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/100/200');
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.out.one {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/100/300');
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.out.two {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.out.three {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/400/300');
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.out.four {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/300/300');
  transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-img="one">foo 1</li>
  <li data-img="two">foo 2</li>
  <li data-img="three">foo 3</li>
  <li data-img="four">foo 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try setTimeout

```js
$("ul li").on("mouseleave",function(){
            $('#pic').removeClass().addClass('zero');
            setTimeout( () => $(this).removeClass('active')}), 1000);
}
```

Comment: You should alse clear the timeout before setting a new one.

Comment: right, in mouseenter you might need to clear if there is a timeout

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```
$("ul li").on("mouseleave",function(){
  setTimeout(function(_this){
    $('#pic').removeClass().addClass('zero');
    $(_this).removeClass('active');
  }, 700, this);
});
```